# Base Address of Process via lua

Tags: powershell, lua

I've been trying to figure out a way through lua in which to return the base address of an exe. Is this possible? I was thinking maybe call powershell thru os.execute but I cant even seem to find any data online about how to retrieve the base address of an exe through powershell. What is the simplest way to return the base address of Calculator via lua?

Comment: the base address like that cheat engine would return if you attached to calculator, "calculator" + offset i need calculators base address

Comment: You can do it directly using FFI if your lua engine supports it. AFAIK that's the address returned by ShellExecute, look around for examples.

Comment: yes Ikn but ffi is not available

Comment: Googled an [example](http://www.mpgh.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1037075&p=11135591&viewfull=1#post11135591) in PS, try adapting it or look for similar using the names of system functions mentioned in that code.